# GRUB menu not showing up

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, crunchbang

I am dualbooting Crunchbang and Windows 8.1. Whenever I start my computer, GRUB appears. However, GRUB appears not as a menu, but as minimal grub bash.

After messing around for a while, the following command brought back the menu:

```
grub> configfile (hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Note: my Crunchbang partition is in /dev/sda8.

I'm not that great with Linux, but I think this means that the GRUB config file is not being used when GRUB is started. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/grub-does-not-list-windows-after-crunchbang-installation

If that doesn't work there is a grub setup command that usually comes with the distro's to install/reinstall grub. the partitions may have been shuffled by an install and grub is confused as to where to find its files. the install utility should update the stage 1 files in the mbr so they know where linux/grub is.

Comment: Do you know the grub command?

Comment: its been forever since I had to use grub1 And it was always on redhat so I am not sure if your distro will be the same.  grub-install  or  maybe going in to grub after the system is booted and running setup.  one of them is pretty automated (the one im thinking of) the other i think you hav to specify information.